# using indexedDB for shopping cart

Tags: shopping-cart, indexeddb

Is making a shopping cart using IndexedDB a good idea rather then the implementation of Sessions and cookies if we support only modern browsers?what difference it can make in comparison with session and cookies?(skipping compatibility issue)

Comment: Don't use IndexedDB you will get compatibility issues, with Safari

Comment: there is a very good library called http://dexie.org/

Comment: I know about compatibility issues. I wanna know about what difference it can make in comparison with session and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexedDB if you need scalability over localStorage, sessionStorage, or cookies. Otherwise there is not much point, as indexedDB is more complicated and slower.